# Using myFuncArray.shift()() to call functions

Tags: javascript

I am having troubles using shift() to call functions I have put in an array. I have put together a simple example illustrating the problem.

Essentially the function gets called, however, the changes to variables in the function do not stick.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
Taco = function() {};
Taco.prototype.init = function() {
  this.ex1 = "ex1 in init()";
  alert(this.ex1);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="Submit" onClick="withShift();" value="withShift"/>
<div id="div1">
</div>
<input type="Submit" onClick="noShift();" value="noShift"/>
<div id="div2">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// This calls init but does not hold the value of ex1 after the call
withShift = function() {
taco = new Taco();
  funcQ = [];
  funcQ.push(taco.init);
  funcQ.shift()(); 

  div1 = document.getElementById("div1")
  div1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taco.ex1));
};

// this calls init and it holds the value...
noShift = function() {
  taco2 = new Taco();
  taco2.init();
  div1 = document.getElementById("div2")
  div1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taco2.ex1));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not remember the `this` argument when you pass method pointers. You have to use the `call` or `apply` method on the function object to explicitly pass `this`.

Using `taco.init` is roughly the same as using `Taco.prototype.init` when it comes to passing function pointers. Here's what would be the working way:

```
taco = new Taco();
funcQ = [];
funcQ.push(taco.init);
// pass taco first, and the non-hidden function arguments after;
// in this case, no other argument
funcQ.shift().call(taco);
```

If you can't use this kind of syntax, you may use anonymous functions:

```
taco = new Taco();
funcQ = [];
funcQ.push(function() { taco.init(); });
funcQ.shift()();
```

In opposition to the `object.method` syntax that doesn't carry the `this` argument, closures are reliable.